# How are the per-zone location proxies actually used and kept up to date in Google Spanner?

Tags: proxy, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-spanner

This is a detail that the [Spanner paper](http://research.google.com/archive/spanner-osdi2012.pdf) glosses over with a single line, and I am hoping someone from Google may be able to shed some light on.

> The per-zone *location proxies* are used by clients to locate the
>   spanservers assigned to serve their data.

1. How do clients figure out the IP addresses of the location proxies?
2. After they retrieve the data, do clients cache this data somewhere or do they talk to the location proxies for every read and write?
3. If there is a cache on the client, how does the client discover that it needs to be updated?

Answer (score 1):

Going to answer the first question, since details of location proxies are not public at this point.

Naming resolution at Google is solved with Borg, see section 2.6 of [the Borg paper](http://static.googleusercontent.com/media/research.google.com/en//pubs/archive/43438.pdf).

Answer (score 1):

Spanner is now a Google Cloud Platform service, so you can review the docs and play with the service.

https://cloud.google.com/spanner/docs/

Basically, we auto-route everything to the nearest version of the data that can respond to your request. You just address the instance and we do the routing, so you can't address a replica directly.

Answer (score -1):

1. How do clients figure out the IP addresses of the location proxies? - as far as I understand client only knows about each DC address, where client is connected
2. After they retrieve the data, do clients cache this data somewhere or do they talk to the location proxies for every read and write? - actually couldn't find any info about caching. I think caching not supported because Spanner is going to store hundreds of petabytes
3. If there is a cache on the client, how does the client discover that it needs to be updated? - client doesn't have local cache